# Need paste event for IE7 (Jquery paste event do not work in IE7)

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7

I know it's quite backward to ask for IE7 support and latest browsers are reliable. But I still need it to fire paste (mouse paste and ctrl+v paste) reliably in an IE7 based tool. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

May be you use incorrect version of JQuery:

> JQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8.

Try to use 1.x version.

Comment: I am using Jquery 1.9.1 but paste event is not working in IE 7.